# How to restrict that method param of type Class cannot be generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have a method:

```
public String getFoo(Class inClass)
```

However, I would like to restrict that `inClass` be an instance of type `BaseType`. Is there a way to do it similar to, for example, the generics way of specifying `ListableEntity<T extends ListItem>`, meaning that a `ListableEntity` must be declared as encapsulating a `ListItem` or any class that extends or implements it?

Comment: Your question and its title are talking about two different things entirely. Which do you mean?

Comment: The answer was so obvious you found it yourself. Well done!

Comment: I meant that the param Class must be an instance of BaseType

Answer (score -1):

I found a way:

```
public String getFoo(Class<? extends BaseType> inClass)
```